Acer Aspire A315-58 fan keeps spinning i try all distros but not solution
I have a problem with the laptop fan, which is always spinning and making an annoying sound. I’ve tried many distros and want to settle on ubuntu 23.10, but the fan is bothering me. Is there any solution? Because I tried all the solutions but nothing worked. The Linux Mint distribution works fine, and the fan only makes noise when I push the processor
All distributions suffer from the same problem with the fan, except for Linux Mint
cpu
11th Gen Intel® Core™ i3-1115G4 × 4

You mention Linux Mint worked, but gave no clues as to what product (Linux Mint's Ubuntu-based product, or Linux Mint Debian Edition) let alone release details and kernel stack used. Ubuntu 23.10 uses a recent 6.5 linux kernel, which compared to your unstated Linux Mint which was using ???  Explore the differences in the software stack that makes up the OS, not just the distro name to explore why it's different & how you can control it.

linux mint kernel 5.15 ubuntu version work nice but ubuntu its self have the problem :), but other distros like Linux mint LMDE and mx linux depian fedora have same problem do you think its the kernel ? pop os have the kernel 5.15 and fan laoud

Linux Mint do not have their own kernels, depending on the product they use Ubuntu or Debian kernels, so the 5.15 was either the GA kernel from Ubuntu 22.04, or HWE kernel from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (both of which are 5.15); thus I'd expect the same if using Ubuntu too (23.10 is a newer release, and not being a LTS release doesn't have kernel stack choice (outside of some OEM options)).  Don't forget to explore kernel modules (not just kernel version!)   This is a Q&A site and not a forum, please add additional details to your question, as the question is what will be answered

how i can explore kernel modules im not very expert with linux and thank you for answering me

lsmod will list the modules being used. Your Linux Mint release will tell you the Ubuntu system its based on (ie. kernel you're using, as 5.15 alone says little as GA stack from one release or HWE stack from another release - Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice). Install media includes various modules available, eg. Lubuntu includes no nvidia kernel modules available (they are installed by users post-install) where as others do include them for use post-install OR at install time, ISO used here is key & not just release, eg. 23.10 Desktop had 2 ISO choices, Server another..

FYI:  The Ubuntu 23.10 ISO choice was more about installer available; you could select to install using ubuntu-desktop-installer (Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop primary ISO), ubiquity (Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop legacy ISO), subiquity (Ubuntu 23.10 Server), with choice of ubiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer or calamares for Ubuntu 23.10 flavors... They differed in packages that were installed by default, as well as what was included (some with OEM kernel stack options, others not) with decision as to what 23.10 gets installed selected at download time & by options at install. 23.10 is vague


Download this tool from software store called "Firmware".Check for any missing firmware there.
I also faced the same problem with my Acer Nitro 5 which has Nvidia GTX 1650 where fans where on the constant blast everytime.
It was missing GPU drivers in my case. Can be any other driver also.
I fixed it by going into Sofware and updates and installing the proprietary drivers.

